# DynamoDB conditional put

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Say I want to add a record like below:

```
{
id:876876,
username:example,
email:xxxxxx@xxx.com,
phone:xxxxxxx,
created_at:current_date,
updated_at:current_date
}
```

What I want is to check with the id if record exist `created_date` should not be modified only `updated_date` should have `current_date`.

Can we do this with put method without having to be making a get item call?

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried so far? Do you already have code available for the creating the item without the condition?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new item or update an existing item with conditional expression. Prefer to use [updateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property) rather than [putItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property).

If the **Hash key (Primary key)** doesn't exist both `putItem` and `updateItem` create a new record. If the record already exist, `putItem` will completely override the existing row but `updateItem` only updates the attributes passed in **UpdateExpression** not a whole record.

In your case, use `if_not_exists()` function to check whether the `created_at` field already exists or not. If exists `created_at` will not be overridden.

**Update expression:** `"SET #email = :email, #created_at = if_not_exists(#created_at, :created_at), #updated_at = :updated_at"`

**Sample snippet**

```
var params = {
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
     "#email": "email", 
     "#created_at": "created_at",
     "#updated_at": "updated_at"
    }, 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":email": {
       S: "test2@grr.la"
      }, 
     ":created_at": {
       S: date.toISOString()
      },
      ":updated_at": {
        S: date.toISOString()
    }
    }, 
    Key: {
     "id": {
       S: "T1"
      }
    }, 
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW", 
    TableName: "stack", 
    UpdateExpression: "SET #email = :email, #created_at = if_not_exists(#created_at, :created_at), #updated_at = :updated_at"
   };
   ddb.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);  
   })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But my need is to just avoid overriding one field created_at.
Other fields can be updated.

I can simply make a get item call and check if record exists then add the same value   for created_at field and update updated_at field with current date time.

Here i need to make two hits to dynamodb but i want to achieve this with single put call. Is there any way.?

Comment: Prefer using updateItem to achieve your requirement. It will avoid performing GET operation and then update operation. Updated the answer as well.